# How to check if a class or CFType is available in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios8, backwards-compatibility, touch-id

I am working in iOS8 right now and I wanted to check if the CFType 'SecAccessControlRef' is available. Since the app will support iOS 7, without a check, the app will crash. For a regular NSClass I would just use a check like

```
if (NSClassFromString('SomeClass') == NULL)
```

but is there something similar for non NSClass items?

Comment: The closest I can find is [this](https://www.secsign.com/fingerprint-validation-as-an-alternative-to-passcodes/) article that just checks whether a users device supports fingerprint validation at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than testing for the *type* itself you can test for one of the functions that support the type. When a framework is weak-linked the address of C functions will be `NULL` if the framework is not present. For example you should be able to use something like:

```
BOOL isSecAccessControlRefAvailable = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags != NULL;
```

See *Using Weakly Linked Methods, Functions, and Symbols* in Apple's [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html).

Comment: Not ideal, but it'll do

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you want but I've used this for a similar type of question:

```
if (&kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly == NULL) {
    return NO; // must be on iOS7
}
```